# Does Collections.sort keep order on equal elements?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I have a list of objects ordered by a date parameter and want to reorder them by category parameter, but keeping the date order within the category.

Is something like this enough, or do I have to implement a comparator that takes on account the date for objects of the same category?

```
// sort the list by category asc(, date asc )
Collections.sort((List<Object>)entries, new Comparator<Object>() {

    @Override public int compare(Object elementA, Object elementB) {
        return elementA.category.compareTo(elementB.category); // what happens when elementA.category.equals(elementB.category)?
    }

});
```

Comment: IMO if you need to sort by something, sort by something--don't leave it to chance, or the result of another sort.

Comment: `Collections.sort` uses `Arrays.sort` behind the scenes, which does a merge sort. The code of that merge sort is [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.mergeSort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29).

Comment: It's always a good idea to read the Javadoc for a method, before asking on Stack Overflow exactly what the method does.  In this particular case, the Javadoc answers your question very, very clearly.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out! I actually found `This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.` on the docs while writing the question, but I was unsure if `equal elements` was refering to the result of the comparator or actually comparing the elements (instead of their properties) with `objectA.equals(objectB)`, which I knew it most probably wasn't going to be the case, but I wanted to be 100% sure (I even did a test to check it out but I wanted some ratification in case it was just coincidence, I guess that was a little paranoid).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The code in your question will do what you need it to, since `Collections.sort()` does preserve the order of equal elements.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)):

> This sort is guaranteed to be *stable*: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

In other words, if the entries are ordered by date before the `sort()`, they will stay ordered by date *within each category* after the `sort()`.

If you don't want to rely on the original ordering, you can easily extend your comparator to first compare the categories and then break ties using the dates.